# Get data from JSON file and export it to XLSX table

Tags: excel, powershell

Unable to convert and export JSON to XLSX file.

I managed to export the data using the following script, but it included some Image URLS. Can you please help me to export the data and filter it?

```
$jsonRequest = Invoke-WebRequest 
$jsonRequest.Content
$csv = $jsonRequest.Content | ConvertFrom-Json
$csv | Export-Csv -Path c:\1233last.csv
```

Comment: "Unable to convert and export" is not a valid problem description. What do you expect the code to do? What does it actually do? Are you getting errors? If so, what do they say? Also, please do not link to off-site resources. Everything that pertains to your question should be *in* your question.

Comment: The answer is there!!  [Convert and format JSON to XLSX](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/a242faf8-c472-4c69-8f6b-81f69526f143/convert-and-format-json-to-xlsx?forum=ITCG#6e40607d-61f0-48aa-b62f-aceba0809fc2)

Comment: If you're aware of PowerQuery(Get Data) in excel, you can extract data from a JSON file and transform it to your desired output.

Answer (score 0):

Since the items can have more than one value for the same ingredient, and the desired output should sum these per ingredient name.
The below code uses a small helper function for that.
Otherwise, it just runs through all items and returns an array of PSObjects with all the properties you need for export to CSV.

```
function Get-Amount ($ingredient,[string]$name) {
    # helper function to return the sum of the ingredient values
    [double]$amount = 0
    $ingredient | where-object {$_.name -eq $name} | ForEach-Object {
        # quick and dirty solution to convert the decimal comma into a decimal point
        $amount += [double]($_.amount.value -replace ',', '.')
    }
    if ($amount) {
         # If your Excel has trouble seeing the values as decimal numbers because
         # of possible culture differences, you can also output 
         # $amount.ToString("G", [System.Globalization.CultureInfo]::InvariantCulture) }
        return $amount
    } 
}

$jsonRequest = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri https://api.punkapi.com/v2/beers
$result = ($jsonRequest.Content | ConvertFrom-Json) | ForEach-Object { 
    # for convenience we store these in local variables
    $hops = $_.ingredients.hops
    $malt = $_.ingredients.malt
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        'Tagline' = $_.tagline
        'Name' = $_.name
        'Fuggles (hops)'                              = Get-Amount $hops 'Fuggles'
        'First Gold (hops)'                           = Get-Amount $hops 'First Gold'
        'Cascade (hops)'                              = Get-Amount $hops 'Cascade'
        'Maris Otter Extra Pale (malt)'               = Get-Amount $malt 'Maris Otter Extra Pale'
        'Caramalt (malt)'                             = Get-Amount $malt 'Caramalt'
        'Munich (malt)'                               = Get-Amount $malt 'Munich'
        'Yeast' = $_.ingredients.yeast
        'Acidulated Malt (malt)'                      = Get-Amount $malt 'Acidulated Malt'
        'Acidulated Malt for kettle souring (malt)'   = Get-Amount $malt 'Acidulated Malt for kettle souring'
        'Ahtanum (hops)'                              = Get-Amount $hops 'Ahtanum'
        'Amarillo (hops)'                             = Get-Amount $hops 'Amarillo'
        'Amber (malt)'                                = Get-Amount $malt 'Amber'
        'Bramling Cross (hops)'                       = Get-Amount $hops 'Bramling Cross'
        'Brown (malt)'                                = Get-Amount $malt 'Brown'
        'Carafa Special Malt Type 1 (malt)'           = Get-Amount $malt 'Carafa Special Malt Type 1'
        'Carafa Special Malt Type 3 (malt)'           = Get-Amount $malt 'Carafa Special Malt Type 3'
        'Centennial (hops)'                           = Get-Amount $hops 'Centennial'
        'Challenger (hops)'                           = Get-Amount $hops 'Challenger'
        'Chinook (hops)'                              = Get-Amount $hops 'Chinook'
        'Chocolate (malt)'                            = Get-Amount $malt 'Chocolate'
        'Citra (hops)'                                = Get-Amount $hops 'Citra'
        'Columbus (hops)'                             = Get-Amount $hops 'Columbus'
        'Columbus Extract (hops)'                     = Get-Amount $hops 'Columbus Extract'
        'Crystal (hops)'                              = Get-Amount $hops 'Crystal'
        'Crystal (malt)'                              = Get-Amount $malt 'Crystal'
        'Crystal 150 (malt)'                          = Get-Amount $malt 'Crystal 150'
        'Dark Crystal (malt)'                         = Get-Amount $malt 'Dark Crystal'
        'Dark Crystal 350-400 (malt)'                 = Get-Amount $malt 'Dark Crystal 350-400'
        'Extra Pale - Spring Blend (malt)'            = Get-Amount $malt 'Extra Pale - Spring Blend'
        'Extra Pale (malt)'                           = Get-Amount $malt 'Extra Pale'
        'Flaked Oats (malt)'                          = Get-Amount $malt 'Flaked Oats'
        'Galena (hops)'                               = Get-Amount $hops 'Galena'
        'Hersbrucker (hops)'                          = Get-Amount $hops 'Hersbrucker'
        'Honey (hops)'                                = Get-Amount $hops 'Honey'
        'Hop Extract (hops)'                          = Get-Amount $hops 'Hop Extract'
        'Lactose (hops)'                              = Get-Amount $hops 'Lactose'
        'Lager Malt (malt)'                           = Get-Amount $malt 'Lager Malt'
        'Magnum (hops)'                               = Get-Amount $hops 'Magnum'
        'Motueka (hops)'                              = Get-Amount $hops 'Motueka'
        'Mt.Hood (hops)'                              = Get-Amount $hops 'Mt.Hood'
        'Nelson Sauvin (hops)'                        = Get-Amount $hops 'Nelson Sauvin'
        'Pale Ale - Tipple (malt)'                    = Get-Amount $malt 'Pale Ale - Tipple'
        'Pale Ale (malt)'                             = Get-Amount $malt 'Pale Ale'
        'Peated Malt (malt)'                          = Get-Amount $malt 'Peated Malt'
        'Peppercorns (hops)'                          = Get-Amount $hops 'Peppercorns'
        'Propino Pale Malt (malt)'                    = Get-Amount $malt 'Propino Pale Malt'
        'Propino Pale Malt for kettle souring (malt)' = Get-Amount $malt 'Propino Pale Malt for kettle souring'
        'Roasted Barley (malt)'                       = Get-Amount $malt 'Roasted Barley'
        'Saaz (hops)'                                 = Get-Amount $hops 'Saaz'
        'Simcoe (hops)'                               = Get-Amount $hops 'Simcoe'
        'Smoked Malt (malt)'                          = Get-Amount $malt 'Smoked Malt'
        'Smoked Weyermann (malt)'                     = Get-Amount $malt 'Smoked Weyermann'
        'Sorachi Ace (hops)'                          = Get-Amount $hops 'Sorachi Ace'
        'Tomahawk (hops)'                             = Get-Amount $hops 'Tomahawk'
        'Waimea (hops)'                               = Get-Amount $hops 'Waimea'
        'Wheat (malt)'                                = Get-Amount $malt 'Wheat'
        'Wheat Malt (malt)'                           = Get-Amount $malt 'Wheat Malt'
        'Willamette (hops)'                           = Get-Amount $hops 'Willamette'
    }
}

$result | Export-Csv -Path c:\1233last.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this script on powerhshell replace the file path with your own from file path next to Get-content and output file next to Out-File.

`Get-Content C:\Temp\PatchingServer.json | ConvertFrom-Json | ConvertTo-Csv | Out-File C:\Temp\Patching.csv`

Reference:https://www.tutorialspoint.com/how-to-convert-json-file-to-csv-file-using-powershell